# Why output showing 0 instead of 0.0?

Tags: c++, arrays, types

I declared an array of 10 elements and initialized it with 0.0 .. 9.9 , its output is perfect except 0.0 has been changed into 0, why is it so?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
int const SIZE = 10;
double number[SIZE] = {0.0,1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6,7.7,8.8,9.9};
for(int i(0) ; i < SIZE ; i++)
{
        cout << number[i] << endl ;
}
system("PAUSE");
}
```

Thanks,

output:
0             //it should be 0.0 not 0//
1.1
2.2
.
.
.
9.9

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::cout` by default will output *up to* 6 digits, which in this case is one (the zero) since no decimals are needed.  `std::cout << (double)1.0;` would display `1`, for instance.  You can use `std::setprecision` from the `<iomanip>` header and `std::fixed` to keep the decimal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main(void)
{
    int const SIZE = 10;
    double number[SIZE] = {0.0,1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6,7.7,8.8,9.9};
    std::cout << std::setprecision(1) << std::fixed;

    for(int i(0) ; i < SIZE ; i++)
    {
        std::cout << number[i] << std::endl ;
    }
}
```

There are lots of helpful i/o manipulators.  [Here's a reference to check it out.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)

Comment: The default for inserting a `double` into `cout` or another stream is not to display as many digits as required to display the number. The default is C’s `%g` format, which uses six digits but removes trailing zeros (after rounding to six digits).

Comment: That setpercision function was helpful in manipulating output of 1.1 till 9.9 but problem still there 0 is still zero even though i initialized 0th element to 0.0 !!

Comment: @ArsalaKamal Make sure you use `fixed` as well.  `setprecision` sets the maximum number of digits rounding, `fixed` makes it so it will always display that number of decimals.  Please read my answer carefully, and check the reference I link at the end.  I have confirmed the output on my end to display `0.0`

Answer (score 6):

“0.0” and “0” are two numerals for the same number. A `double` stores only the number<sup>1</sup>; it does not store the original numeral.

When the source text of a C++ program contains a numeral such as `0.0` or `1.1`, the compiler converts it from that numeral (which is a string of characters) to a `double`. The `double` format only represents numbers, not the strings they came from. So, a zero in `double` is just zero; it is not “0” or “0.0” or “0.000”. When you print it, there is no way for software that prints a `double` to know whether the original numeral was “0” or “0.0”. It just prints it according to the rules for printing a `double`.

By default, a `double` value of zero is printed as “0”. If you wish it to be printed differently, you can use I/O manipulators to ask that it be formatted differently. For example, after you `#include <iomanip>`, you can use `std::cout << std::setprecision(1) << std::fixed;` to set the floating-point output format to one digit in a fixed (versus scientific) format. Then printing a `double` value of zero will produce “0.0”.

---

<sup>1</sup> Except, for zero, `double` can distinguish +0 and –0 (when IEEE 754 is used for floating-point).

Answer (score 4):

That is simply how `cout` works by default. To change that, you can either:

1. use the `precision()` method:

   ```
   cout.precision(1);
   for(int i(0) ; i < SIZE ; i++)
   {
       cout << number[i] << endl ;
   }
   ```
2. Use `setprecision()`:

   ```
   #include <iomanip>

   cout << setprecision(1) << fixed;
   for(int i(0) ; i < SIZE ; i++)
   {
       cout << number[i] << endl ;
   }
   ```

Comment: That setpercision function was helpful in manipulating output of 1.1 till 9.9 but problem still there 0 is still zero even though i initialized 0th element to 0.0 !!

Comment: There's really no difference in initializing a double to 0 or 0.0, or 0.00, etc.  In order to use `setprecision`, however, you have to `#include <iomanip>` with your other `include` statements.  Otherwise, use `cout.precision` as Remy also demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to output 0.0 rather than 0, look into `#include <iomanip>`

Answer (score 1):

The normal format will use a representation a compact as possible in most cases. Since binary floating point numbers are normalized, they don't represent any trailing digits. If you want to have an extra fractional position, you might want to use these flags:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1);
```

The entire program would look like this:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int const SIZE = 10;
    double number[SIZE] = {0.0,1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6,7.7,8.8,9.9};
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1);
    for(int i(0) ; i != SIZE ; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << number[i] << '\n';
    }
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: Yeah i used what you said setprecision function but still have problem, please see edited version of my question including output.

Comment: @ArsalaKamal: I don't see any change in your original indicating that you used my suggestion. Also, using the suggestion clearly prints all values with one digits.

Comment: I did experiment on my IDE your suggestion is working fine with 1st element till last element of array, but problem is still there that is 0th element is still displaying 0 instead of 0.0 even i initialized it to 0.0

Comment: @ArsalaKamal: If I ran the code as posted in my updated response, the first element certainly gets printed as `0.0` as it should: the C++ standard mandates the formatting as `0.0` and I'm not aware of any platform which doesn't do so. Which IDE are you using? I'm currently sitting in a room with pretty much all standard C++ library implementers (i.e., the C++ standardization committee meeting) and I could quickly verify if the used standard C++ library is, indeed, broken.